# Accessing a server that is accessible to one computer from another computer

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, forwarding, remote-connection

So basically I have a computer, let's call it 'X'.

This computer has a standard Internet connection, via which it connects to a VPN, using CheckPoint VPN.

When it's connected to the VPN (and only then) it can access a server. Let's call it 'Y'. So I can ping 'Y' and receive a response, and also interact with 'Y' in various ways.

Now I have a separate computer, let's call it 'Z'. It to the Internet also, but not to the VPN, as it doesn't have any VPN software on it, and I have no idea how to copy CheckPoint VPN to it.

I want to be able to access server 'Y' from computer 'Z', through computer 'X''s VPN connection.

Is there any possible way to do this?

I thought TeamViewer VPN might be able to, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is there some other technology I can use for this, like "tunnelling" or a "proxy" or whatever?

I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to networking, so apologies if this is difficult to read.

Comment: I'm going to try using OpenVPN for this.

Comment: On second thoughts, maybe SSH is the right thing to try. (Found a similar question here: http://superuser.com/questions/226420/accessing-internal-server-from-outside-through-ssh?rq=1). I'll try BitVise WinSSHD.

Comment: Which OSes are you using on X and Z? Also, do you have an ethernet cable?

Comment: Windows 2008 R2 Server. I've finally gotten it partially working with an app called 'ReDirProxy'. By this means I can access VPN servers through the browser on my client machine. Unfortunately I still can't use Git to access the git server on my client machine. I'm thinking maybe Git isn't using my Windows proxy settings?

Comment: Just discovered that this is occurring because the Git repo I'm trying to access uses SSH rather than HTTP. I'll have to use a tunnelling utility such as Corkscrew.

Comment: Ughh... tried using proxytunnel but to no avail. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to solve this by using a combination of [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com) VPN and a small proxy app called [ReDirProxy](http://redirproxy.bplaced.net/).

The steps were as follows:

1. Install TeamViewer on host machine (laptop X), with 'VPN' setting.
2. Install TeamViewer on client machine (laptop Z), with 'VPN' setting.
3. Connect client machine to host machine on TeamViewer VPN. (Refer TeamViewer documentation).
4. Download and install ReDirProxy onto the host machine. Run it and click 'Start' button (top-right). Note which port is selected (option buttons on the lower-right).
5. On client machine, go to the TeamCity VPN window, copy the 'IP of Partner' address to the clipboard.
6. Still on the client, go to Internet Options (Start -> type 'Internet Options'), Connections tab, Lan settings (lower-right), tick the checkbox under Proxy Settings, paste in the IP address that was copied to the clipboard in step 5, and the port number that was selected into the port number field. Click OK then OK.

After following these steps, I was able to enter the address of a VPN-only website and browse to it from my client laptop.